# ASP.Net Core and AngularJS: How to have dynamic route/content based on Database record?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, routes, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to have a system where the first URL sub-directory will be dynamic but also act as the query to the dynamic content shown on the page. Is this possible?

For example, the user will be able to enter the address like so:

`http://localhost:8885/chase/`

`http://localhost:8885/bank-of-america/`

`http://localhost:8885/.../`

How would I be able to tie in a query to `chase` or `bank-of-america` and populate the page with dynamic content IF the record exists, otherwise to redirect to a "default" view like "This page DNE".

Let's say my `AppController.cs` handles these queries like so:

```
public JsonResult DirectoryQuery(string subDomain) {
    return _context.Banks
        .Where(t => t.ExtName == subDomain)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then, my angular controller makes that query, something like this:

```
app.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $location, LookupService) {

    var urlString = $location.path();

    (function() {
        LookupService.CheckURL(urlString).then(function(data) {
            if (data == null) {
                window.location.pathname = '404';
            }
            else {
                console.log('This page exists');
            }
        }
    })();
})
.factory('LookupService', function($http) {
    var LookupServiceData = {};

    LookupServiceData.CheckURL = function(data) {
        return $http({
            url: '/App/DirectoryQuery',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {'content-type'" 'application/json'}
        });
    };

    return LookupServiceData;
});
```

I'm using the `MapRoute` ASP.Net Core configuration, but don't know exactly how to set this up. Here's what I'm thinking it is so far, (located in the `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(config =>
{
    config.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        template: "{bank?}/{controller?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "App", action = "Index" }
        );
});
```

**NOTE**: I don't have `{bank?}` defined anywhere, and don't know if this is even proper terminology.

If someone has a route solution via AngularJS and not C#, I'm open to this as well! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I would set your ASP map route template back to the original default value: `template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}")` and create a controller specifically for your bank requests, like so:

```
[Route("Bank")]
public class BankController : Controller
{
    private IBankService BankService;

    public BankController(IBankService bankService) {
        BankService = bankService ?? new IBankService();
    }


    [HttpGet("{bankStringId}")]
    public string Index(string bankStringId)
    {
        var result = someServiceMethod(bankStringId);
        return result;
    }

}
```

The addition of the `Bank` portion of the route disambiguates between calling your app route and your bank api call.  Then, in your AngularJS app, have your service make calls to the controller with URIs in this format: `http://localhost:8885/bank/chase/`.